# Abnormal Extruding

Tags: extruder

My printer stops about every 5 minutes and it gives me the error message "Abnormal Extruding". I have changed the heat setting up and down on the extruder, but it doesn't help. I have adjusted the bed, the speed and the problem is still there. Can someone help, please and thank you

Comment: Hi Nelson and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Please [edit] your question and add what type of printer you have. It might be beneficial to add the extruder type and what you are printing and how you created the print files.

Comment: without more information, we can't possibly help. What circumstances, what printer, is that just one gCode or all?

Comment: Please help us help you, add the printer type and firmware type, otherwise it is impossible to help you! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to update your question so that it is possible for people to help you. If you found a solution, please share this by posting your answer and accept it after 48 hours.